# How to make Report Server skip database authentication and hide parameters prompt

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new on Report Server and I'm facing two problems.

I'll give you some information and then I explain them.

I've created a Report Server Project and inside it, I also created a Shared Data Source, which has the user ID and password to grant access to a Sql Server 2005 Data Base. But my report server was created on Sql Server 2008 R2.

After I created the Shared Data Source, I made a Shared DataSet, which uses the Shared Data Source as Data Source. The command type used on this DataSet was "Stored Procedure", this procedure receives parameters, so, the DataSet also receive these parameters.

Then, I created a Report, I drag the DataSet to this Report and it automatically created the parameters report.

Let's separate the problems...

First Problem: How to Hide the Report Parameters Prompts when the Report is accessed by URL

When I run the Report by righ-clicking the .rdl file and click on "Run", the parameters prompt aren't shown, but when the report is accessed from outside (after it is deployed on the Report Server) by URL, the parameters prompts are shown.

What can I do to change this behavior? I've already tried to set the tag as following:

```
<Hidden>true</Hidden>
```

But it keeps doing the same thing.

The following is the code snippet of my Report Parameters.

```
<ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="IDFUNC">
        <DataType>Integer</DataType>
        <DefaultValue>
            <Values>
                <Value>
                    10
                </Value>
            </Values>
        </DefaultValue>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="dtInicial">
        <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        <DefaultValue>
            <Values>
                <Value>
                    06/01/2012
                </Value>
            </Values>
        </DefaultValue>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="dtFinal">
        <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
        <DefaultValue>
            <Values>
                <Value>
                    09/01/2012
                </Value>
            </Values>
        </DefaultValue>
    </ReportParameter>
</ReportParameters>
```

I've already tried to make these parameters Hidden on the Report Parameter Properties Dialog Box too. But in this case I get the message error "<Prompt:> Enter a prompt for the parameter".

Just to be clear, I'll pass the parameters I need by QueryString (URL).

Second Problem: Report asks for Data Base Credentials when loading the Report (just when by accessed by URL)

How to make the Report skip the Data Base authentication when it is accessed by URL?

Well guys, this is everything.
If you want more information to help me, just ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is propogation issues: Reporting Services doesn't propogate authentication credentials so you need to open the datasource on the server using the browser and open its properties and enter the credentials in there again. This is done for security reasons and you only need to update the credentials on the server once.

Similarly, sometimes when parameters change they don't get propogated either (if the Reporting Services server thinks you have modified the parameters from their deployed settings - it keeps the modified values for you). You may need to update the parameters on the server again using the browser. Select Manage Parameters for that report and set them to hidden. Deleting and re-deploying the report may also work.

Comment: Thanks Chris. You helped me a lot. As I never heard about Reporting Services before the beginning of this week, hints like that save lifes.